# Cannot set cookies in new blank HTML page

Tags: javascript, cookies

Ok, basic cookies question. I'm totally new to cookies.

When I open up the Chrome console on a website that has cookies, I can set:

```
document.cookie = encodeURIComponent("name1") + "=" + encodeURIComponent("value1")
```

to set a cookie. Sure enough calling `document.cookie` reveals the string of cookies with the new one (`name1=value1`) included in it. When I do exactly the same as the above in the console on a new empty html page that I've made, it doesn't work. Calling `document.cookie` both before and after

```
document.cookie = encodeURIComponent("name1") + "=" + encodeURIComponent("value1")
```

returns `""`.

Is there some initialisation step I'm missing? I'm working from Nicholas Zakas' Javascript book and am just trying stuff out as I go along. I will accept the answer "keep reading" if that's what I need to do.

Comment: What is the scheme component of the URL of the new blank HTML page that you are using for testing?

Comment: `file:` it's running locally

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are an HTTP feature. They aren't well supported across browsers for documents not loaded over HTTP.

Install an HTTP server and do your testing through that.